# Transform one data structure into another data structure JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I have a rowdata as below:

```
export const ROWDATA: Array<any> = [
    {
        id: "1",
        start_time: "9:00:00",
        end_time: "9:30:00",
        day_of_week: 'monday',
        lesson: "Lesson ABC",
        class: "Class ABC",
        room: "room1",
        education_grade_subject: "Physics",
        staff: "Amanda Jeremy",
        timetable: "class timetable",
        modified_user: "admin",
        modified: "2017-01-15",
        created_user: "admin",
        created: "2017-01-15"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        start_time: "9:30:00",
        end_time: "10:00:00",
        day_of_week: 'monday',
        lesson: "Lesson XYZ",
        class: "Class ABC",
        room: "room2",
        education_grade_subject: "Chemistry",
        staff: "Amanda Jeremy",
        timetable: "class timetable",
        modified_user: "admin",
        modified: "2017-01-15",
        created_user: "admin",
        created: "2017-01-15"
    },
   .....

];
```

Basically its a row data structure for a table in my website. The row data i retrieved from my backend. Now I need to convert/transform this data into another format for my website. The new format need to be in following format:

```
export const DATA: Array<any> = [
    {
        time: "9:00", 
        monday: [
                    {
                        class: 'room1', 
                        title: {field: "lesson", text:"Lesson ABC", class:"lessonABC-title"}, 
                        content: [
                            {field: "education_grade_subject", text: "Physics", class:"lessonABC-subject-class"},
                            {field: "staff", text: "Amanda Jeremy", class:"lessonABC-staff-class"}, 
                            {field: "room", text: "Room 01", class:"lessonABC-room-class"}
                            ], 
                        uid: "1"
                    }
                ]
    },

    {
        time: "9:30", 
        monday: [
                    {class: 'room2', 
                        title: {field: "lesson", text:"Lesson XYZ", class:"lessonXYZ-title"}, 
                        content: [
                            {field: "education_grade_subject", text: "Chemistry", class:"lessonXYZ-subject-class"},
                            {field: "staff", text: "Amanda Jeremy", class:"lessonXYZ-teacher-class"}, 
                            {field: "room", text: "Room 02", class:"lessonXYZ-room-class"}
                            ], 
                        uid: "2"
                    }
                ]
    },
....
```

The second data or transformed purely based on the first data. How can I achieve this guys? Very new to JavaScript. Any idea guys? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can start by looking at [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Can give me a model based on the question Saravana?

Comment: For a normal mapping I can do. But i feel its too complicated to achiev

Comment: The type annotation has degraded the quality of your code. Do not use `any` but rather let TypeScript infer a precise type from the assignment. Remove the text `: Array<any>` from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed some of the typescript bits here because they are not really relevant, as I believe the main issue is the logic to parse your `ROWDATA` variable. Have a look at the code below, I've included some comments to explain how it works.

```js
const ROWDATA = [
    {
        id: "1",
        start_time: "9:00:00",
        end_time: "9:30:00",
        day_of_week: 'monday',
        lesson: "Lesson ABC",
        class: "Class ABC",
        room: "room1",
        education_grade_subject: "Physics",
        staff: "Amanda Jeremy",
        timetable: "class timetable",
        modified_user: "admin",
        modified: "2017-01-15",
        created_user: "admin",
        created: "2017-01-15"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        start_time: "9:30:00",
        end_time: "10:00:00",
        day_of_week: 'monday',
        lesson: "Lesson XYZ",
        class: "Class ABC",
        room: "room2",
        education_grade_subject: "Chemistry",
        staff: "Amanda Jeremy",
        timetable: "class timetable",
        modified_user: "admin",
        modified: "2017-01-15",
        created_user: "admin",
        created: "2017-01-15"
    },
];

const group = [];
const map ={}; // keep track of the time that we have seen
ROWDATA.forEach(e => {
  // object to be inserted to the day array in each of the object containing
  // time property
  const newClass = {
    class: e.class
    // ... fill in the rest of info here...
  }
  
  // if time does not exist in map,
  // create new entry
  if (!map[e.start_time]) {
    map[e.start_time] = true;
    const newEntry = { time: e.start_time };
    newEntry[e.day_of_week] = [];
    newEntry[e.day_of_week].push(newClass);
    group.push(newEntry);
  } else {
    // time already exist, find that object with corresponding time
    // and push the new class to the respective day
    group.map(e2 => {
      if (e.start_time === e2.time) {
        if (e2[e.day_of_week]) {
          e2[e.day_of_week].push(newClass);
        } else {
          console.log('!!!')
          e2[e.day_of_week] = [];
          e2[e.day_of_week].push(newClass);
        }
      }
      return e2;
    });
  }
});

console.log(group)
```

Comment: Great let me try D-reaper

Comment: Great Thanks a lot D-reaper

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what parts of this you need to be dynamic since to me it looks like you are hand-picking certain properties and naming some things based on an obvious pattern arbitrarily.

But anyways if you want to run your first data set through a function to get the second output, you can do this:

```
let newdata = ROWDATA.map(item => {
    return {
      time: item.start_time,
      [item.day_of_week]: [{
       class: item.room,
        title: {
          field: "lesson",
          text: item.lesson,
          class: "lesson"+item.lesson.substr(item.lesson.length-3)+"-title"
        }
        content: [{ 
          field: "education_grade_subject", 
          text: item.education_grade_subject, 
          class:"lesson"+item.lesson.substr(item.lesson.length-3)+"-subject-class"
        }, { 
          field: "staff", 
          text: item.staff, 
          class:"lesson"+item.lesson.substr(item.lesson.length-3)+"-staff-class"
        }, { 
          field: "room", 
          text: item.room, 
          class:"lesson"+item.lesson.substr(item.lesson.length-3)+"-room-class"
        }]
      }],
      uid: item.id
    };
});

console.log(newdata);
```

link: https://es6console.com/j219msmv/

Answer (score 0):

## Heres a solution.

Sorry that I'm uses Ramda.js but Ramda.js helped me reduce the amount of code.

```js
const ROWDATA = [
    {
        "class": "Class ABC",
        created: "2017-01-15",
        created_user: "admin",
        day_of_week: "monday",
        education_grade_subject: "Physics",
        end_time: "9:30:00",
        id: "1",
        lesson: "Lesson ABC",
        modified: "2017-01-15",
        modified_user: "admin",
        room: "room1",
        staff: "Amanda Jeremy",
        start_time: "9:00:00",
        timetable: "class timetable"
    },
    {
        "class": "Class ABC",
        created: "2017-01-15",
        created_user: "admin",
        day_of_week: "monday",
        education_grade_subject: "Chemistry",
        end_time: "10:00:00",
        id: "2",
        lesson: "Lesson XYZ",
        modified: "2017-01-15",
        modified_user: "admin",
        room: "room2",
        staff: "Amanda Jeremy",
        start_time: "9:30:00",
        timetable: "class timetable"
    }
]


const formatRoom = 
  R.pipe(R.last, R.prepend("0"), R.takeLast(2), R.join(""), (n) => `Room ${n}`)

const makeClass = (classSuffix) =>
  R.pipe(R.prop('lesson'), R.split(" "), R.last, (name) => `lesson${name}${classSuffix}`,)

const spec = {
  class: R.prop('room'),
  uid: R.prop('id'),
  title: {
    field: R.always('lesson'),
    text: R.prop('lesson'),
    class: makeClass("-title"),
  },
  content: [
    {
      field: R.always('education_grade_subject'),
      text: R.prop('education_grade_subject'),
      class: makeClass("-subject-class"),
    },
    {
      field: R.always('staff'),
      text: R.prop('staff'),
      class: makeClass("-teacher-class"),
    },
    {
      field: R.always('room'),
      text: R.pipe(R.prop('room'), formatRoom),
      class: makeClass("-room-class"),
    },
  ],
}

const formatTime =
  R.dropLast(3)

const transformData =
  R.pipe(
    R.groupBy(R.prop('start_time')),
    R.map(R.groupBy(R.prop('day_of_week'))),
    R.map(R.map(R.map(R.applySpec(spec)))),
    R.toPairs,
    R.map(([start_time, groupsByDay]) =>
      R.assoc('time', formatTime(start_time), groupsByDay)),
  )

console.log(transformData(ROWDATA))
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@0.25.0/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```